# Difference in built-in-methods

Tags: javascript, object, methods

```
var a = "hello world";
var b = 3.14159;

a.length;               
a.toUpperCase();
```

In above code why `toUppercase` method needs to be called but not the `length` method? Both of them are built-in methods in JS, but what is the difference?
Thank you.

Comment: `length` is not a method, it's a property. Hence it doesn't need to be executed, it just holds a value. `toUpperCase` will run code.

Comment: I believe length is property whereas toUpperCase is method defined on prototype chain. That's why length doesn't need to have brackets as it's the property